# xml serialization and Inherited Types

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer, inherited, xmlinclude

I got the error "{"The type Device1 was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}"

Currently I have:

```
public abstract class Device
{
   ..
} 

public class Device1 : Device
{ ... }

[Serializable()]
public class DeviceCollection : CollectionBase
{ ... }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Devices")]
public class XMLDevicesContainer
{
    private DeviceCollection _deviceElement = new DeviceCollection();

    /// <summary>Devices device collection xml element.</summary>
    [XmlArrayItem("Device", typeof(Device))]
    [XmlArray("Devices")]
    public DeviceCollection Devices
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceElement;
        }
        set
        {
            _deviceElement = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and i am doing:

```
        XMLDevicesContainer devices = new XMLDevicesContainer();
        Device device = new Device1();

        device.DeviceName = "XXX";
        device.Password = "Password";

        devices.Devices.Add(device);
        Serializer.SaveAs<XMLDevicesContainer>(devices, @"c:\Devices.xml", new Type[] { typeof(Device1) });
```

serializer does:

```
   public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, XmlWriter writer, Type[] extraTypes)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);
        xs.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }
```

I fall on the last line in the serializer method (xs.Serialize) on the error: "{"The type Device1 was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}"

I tried to write XmlInclude on the Device class. not helped.
If I change the line

```
    [XmlArrayItem("Device", typeof(Device))]
```

to be

```
     [XmlArrayItem("Device", typeof(Device1))]
```

then it works, but I want to write array of multiple Device types.

Answer (score 5):

You must add the XmlIncludeAttribute for each subclass you want to be available on the XMLDevicesContainer class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Devices")]
[XMLInclude(typeof(Device1))]
[XMLInclude(typeof(Device2))]
public class XMLDevicesContainer
{
:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `XmlSerializer` as follows:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj), extraTypes);
```

I had the same problem with a WCF webservice i implemented previously. I had `(object obj)` as a parameter & I was declaring my `XmlSerializer` like `new XmlSerializer(typeof(object))`, which wasn't known statically.
Changing it to `new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())` solved it.